# I'm adding gtm tag in magento 2 in head from admin but it is showing inside body why?

Tags: magento2, javascript, head

I'm adding gtm tag in magento 2 in head from admin but it is showing inside body why?
All script tag are moving in body I have (Move JS to bottom from yes to No) but it is showing in body.

Comment: We have two options to add, one is from Admin which you added but not working. The second option is via code file so try this.

Comment: I have tried both when i try to add code in file all script file are going in body instead of head.

Comment: May I know in which file you wrote that code?

Comment: I have created a demo js file in XML in head but it should bhe shown in head but is couldn't

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any solution got?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?
I have the same exact issue on a Magento 2.4.4-p5.